# name of rgb colors in python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote the following code, but I have a problem that I want the name to be displayed in addition to the color code, but I do not know how
I also tested the web color, but for a closer color function, I do not know how to work in the following code What are the code snippet to enter the color name?

```
import cv2
import webcolors
img_path = r"C:\Users\MJBakhshi\Downloads\color palette.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = cv2.resize(img, (700, 500))

clicked = False
r = g = b = xpos = ypos = 0

def draw_function(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        global b, g, r, xpos, ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        b, g, r = img[y, x]
        b = int(b)
        g = int(g)
        r = int(r)


cv2.namedWindow('color')
cv2.setMouseCallback('color', draw_function)
colorname = webcolors.rgb_to_name((255, 255, 255))
text=colorname+'r='+str(r)+'b='+str(b)+'g='+str(g)


while(1):

    cv2.imshow("color",img)
    if (clicked):

        text = ' R=' + str(r) + ' G=' + str(g) + ' B=' + str(b)

        cv2.rectangle(img,(20,20), (750,60), (b,g,r), -1)


        cv2.putText(img, text,(50,50),2,0.8,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        if(r+g+b>=600):
            cv2.putText(img, text,(50,50),2,0.8,(0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        clicked=False

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the `spec` parameter in the function `webcolors.rgb_to_name`. The correct usage of the function is ,

```
colorname = webcolors.rgb_to_name((255, 255, 255),spec='css3')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not have many colors and I want to output the closest available color, what should I do?

Comment: I don't get your question very well, but if you want the nearest color of a **RGB values**, you can use `webcolors.normalize_integer_triplet(rgb_triplet)` method. You can check the documentations [here](https://webcolors.readthedocs.io/en/1.5/contents.html#webcolors.normalize_integer_triplet)